# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.prodId')

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-navigation

i want to navigate to other screen while clicking on icon in naviagtion and passing a value but there is error
here is the component from where i want to navigate through passing the values

```
const UserProductScreen = (props) => {
  const userProducts = useSelector((state) => state.products.userProducts);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const editProductHandler = (id) => {
    props.navigation.navigate('editProduct', {
      prodId: id,
    });
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={userProducts}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={(itemData) => (
        <ProductItem
          image={itemData.item.imageUrl}
          title={itemData.item.title}
          price={itemData.item.price}
          onselect={() => {
            editProductHandler(itemData.item.id);
          }}>
          <Button
            title="Edit"
            onPress={() => {
              editProductHandler(itemData.item.id);
            }}
          />
          <Button
            title="Delete"
            onPress={() => {
              dispatch(productAction.deleteProduct(itemData.item.id));
            }}
          />
        </ProductItem>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default UserProductScreen;
```

here is the component in which i receive the value passed by other component

```
const EditProductScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
  const {prodId} = route.params;

  const editedProduct = useSelector((state) =>
    state.products.userProducts.find((prod) => prod.id === prodId),
  );

  const [title, setTitle] = useState(editedProduct ? editedProduct.title : '');
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(
    editedProduct ? editedProduct.imageUrl : '',
  );
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(
    editedProduct ? editedProduct.description : '',
  );

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.form}>
        <View style={styles.formControl}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Title</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={title}
            onChangeText={(text) => setTitle(text)}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.formControl}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Image url</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={imageUrl}
            onChangeText={(text) => setImageUrl(text)}
          />
        </View>
        {editedProduct ? null : (
          <View style={styles.formControl}>
            <Text style={styles.label}>Price</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              value={price}
              onChangeText={(text) => setPrice(text)}
            />
          </View>
        )}
        <View style={styles.formControl}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Description</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={description}
            onChangeText={(text) => setDescription(text)}
          />
        </View>

        {editedProduct ? (
          <Button
            title="updated"
            onPress={() => {
              dispatch(
                productsAction.updateProduct(
                  prodId,
                  title,
                  description,
                  imageUrl,
                ),
              );
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <Button
            title="Add product"
            onPress={() => {
              dispatch(
                productsAction.createProduct(
                  title,
                  description,
                  imageUrl,
                  price,
                ),
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  form: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  formControl: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  label: {
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  input: {
    paddingHorizontal: 2,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderBottomColor: '#ccc',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
});

export default EditProductScreen;
```

here is the file in which navigation code exists

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Stackorder = createStackNavigator();
const StackUserProduct = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const stacknavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Product"
        component={ProductOverviewScreen}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerTitle: 'Products',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#273469',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#EBF2FA',
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Cart')}>
              <Icon name="cart-plus" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
              <Icon name="align-justify" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Detail"
        component={ProductDetailScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Detail',
          headerTintColor: '#EBF2FA',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#273469',
          },
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Cart"
        component={CartScreen}
        options={{
          headerTitle: 'Orders',
          headerTintColor: '#EBF2FA',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#273469',
          },
        }}
      />

      <Stack.Screen
        name="order"
        component={OrderScreen}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerTitle: 'Order',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#273469',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#EBF2FA',
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
              <Icon name="align-justify" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const stacknavigatorOrder = () => {
  return (
    <Stackorder.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="order"
        component={OrderScreen}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerTitle: 'Order',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#273469',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#EBF2FA',
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
              <Icon name="align-justify" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
    </Stackorder.Navigator>
  );
};

const stacknavigatorUserProduct = () => {
  return (
    <StackUserProduct.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="userProduct"
        component={UserProductScreen}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerTitle: 'User Products',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#273469',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#EBF2FA',
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('editProduct')}>
              <Icon name="pencil" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
              <Icon name="align-justify" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="editProduct"
        component={EditProductScreen}
        options={({navigation}) => ({
          headerTitle: 'User Products',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#273469',
          },
          headerTintColor: '#EBF2FA',
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                console.log();
              }}>
              <Icon name="check" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
              <Icon name="align-justify" style={styles.iconstyle} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
        })}
      />
    </StackUserProduct.Navigator>
  );
};

const ShopNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Products">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Products" component={stacknavigator} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Order" component={stacknavigatorOrder} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Admin" component={stacknavigatorUserProduct} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  iconstyle: {
    margin: 15,
    color: '#EBF2FA',
  },
});

export default ShopNavigator;
```

Comment: So to be clear your `editProductHandler` is what's failing? Because your headerRight button's onPress doesn't pass params on navigate, so that wouldn't work also.